# Kudu drivers for scala 2.12

Tags: kudu, apache-kudu, scala-2.12

Are there any Apache Kudu drivers for Scala 2.12? And if not, are they planned?

And if not, is this a warning sign that Apache Kudu is not going to be developed any more?

I am able to work with Kudu from Spark 2.4 and Scala 2.11, but I would prefer to migrate to Scala 2.12

```
  , "org.apache.kudu" % "kudu-client" % "1.6.0-cdh5.14.4"
  // At this time, the Kudu libraries are only available for Scala 2.11
  , "org.apache.kudu" %% "kudu-spark2" % "1.4.0" excludeAll(
    ExclusionRule(organization = "org.apache.kudu", name = "kudu-client")
  )
```

Comment: Probably related issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KUDU-3128

Answer (score 3):

There is an [email by Grant Henke](https://www.mail-archive.com/user@kudu.apache.org/msg01387.html), which explains how to build it on your own (for now, it's not published):

> I filed KUDU-3128 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KUDU-3128 to
> track adjusting the build to also compile and publish a 2.12 version
> of kudu-spark.
>
> For now you should be able to build your own by updating the Spark
> version in dependencies.gradle:
> https://github.com/apache/kudu/blob/master/java/gradle/dependencies.gradle#L55
>
> To build the Jar, in the java directory, run :
> `*./gradlew :kudu-spark:assemble*`
>
> *You can also run all the tests with:*
> `*./gradlew :kudu-spark:test*`
>
> The jar can then be found at:
>
> `*./kudu-spark/build/libs/kudu-spark2_2.12-{version}.jar*`

As for the future, I guess you can [subscribe to the mailing list](https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@kudu.apache.org) and ask.